# Creating SDLC and Requirement Board for Uber Development on Trello Body:

Tags: project, trello, sdlc

I am a student tasked with creating a Software Development Life Cycle (SDLC) and a requirement board for an Uber on Trello. My professor provided the general direction, but I'm facing challenges in identifying the modules for the development. I have conducted some research, but the information is overwhelming, leading to confusion.
https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk/tree/master. I tried using this repository.

**Specific Questions:**

1. **Module Identification:**

   - Can someone provide guidance on identifying the key modules/components essential for an Uber-like application? What are the core functionalities I should focus on?
2. **High-Level Requirements:**

   - Once I identify the modules, how should I define high-level requirements for each module? Are there any best practices or templates available?
3. **Trello Board Setup:**

   - What is the recommended way to set up a Trello board for SDLC? Are there specific lists or cards that should be created initially?